# Modify existing plugin function using filter (without modifying the plugin directly)

Tags: customization, filters

I have the following function inside an existing plugin:

```
public static function init() {

    add_filter( 'wcs_view_subscription_actions', __CLASS__ . '::add_edit_address_subscription_action', 10, 2 );
}

public static function add_edit_address_subscription_action( $actions, $subscription ) {

        if ( $subscription->needs_shipping_address() && $subscription->has_status( array( 'active', 'on-hold' ) ) ) {
            $actions['change_address'] = array(
                'url'  => add_query_arg( array( 'subscription' => $subscription->get_id() ), wc_get_endpoint_url( 'edit-address', 'shipping' ) ),
                'name' => __( 'Change Address', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ),
            );
        }

    return $actions;
}
```

I am trying to modify this, so that I can add something to the `$actions` array. Is this possible without modifying the plugin directly, can I do it by filtering in the `functions.php` file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply use the same filter with [a lower or higher priority parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/#parameters) to make the appropriate changes to the `$actions` array. That way you may create a small custom plugin (or modify the theme's `functions.php` file), without having to modify the existing plugin directly.

For example: if you want your custom code to execute after `add_edit_address_subscription_action` function, then use a bigger priority argument (lower priority) to the `wcs_view_subscription_actions` filter.

Sample CODE (use this as part of a custom plugin or in your theme's `functions.php` file):

```
// original filter uses priority 10, so priority 11 will make sure that this function executes after the original implementation
add_filter( 'wcs_view_subscription_actions', 'wpse_custom_action_after', 11, 2 );

function wpse_custom_action_after( $actions, $subscription ) {
    // your custom changes to $actions array HERE
    // this will be executed after add_edit_address_subscription_action function 
    return $actions;
}
```

On the other hand, if you want your custom code to execute before `add_edit_address_subscription_action` function, then use a smaller priority argument (higher priority).

Sample CODE (use this as part of a custom plugin or in your theme's `functions.php` file):

```
// original filter uses priority 10, so priority 9 will make sure that this function executes before the original implementation
add_filter( 'wcs_view_subscription_actions', 'wpse_custom_action_before', 9, 2 );    
function wpse_custom_action_before( $actions, $subscription ) {
    // your custom changes to $actions array HERE
    // this will be executed before add_edit_address_subscription_action function 
    return $actions;
}
```

Comment: I have a function on another plugin, in that function, I want to add some extra code to check a condition and if that is true, I need that function to work. How can I do it without touching the code of that plugin?  In the above answer, I can see you have added filter, but in my case, I can't see any filter hook available in the plugin which i can use.  Please guide me a bit, here is my code https://codepen.io/Nimesh58/pen/RwPRaaP

Comment: @Nimesh: Generally similar implementation should work, i.e. find the filter or action hook that called the function you want to modify and then create another function and use the same hook with higher priority to execute the new custom function. However, every implementation is different, so if the above suggestion doesn't work for your case, better ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change `$actions` array in `functions.php` with your own function.

```
function your_function_name( $actions, $subscription ) {
    // here you can modify $actions array
    // 
    return $actions;
}

add_filter( 'wcs_view_subscription_actions', 'your_function_name', 15, 2 );
```